# Are private members included in TypeInfo Declared properties?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

Does the new `TypeInfo` class include private members by default in its "DeclaredXXX" properties?

Comment: Can't you just write few lines of code and test it by yourself?

Comment: I can but none should have to, since it's a very fundamental question. It's not documented anywhere easily accessible so anyone who wants to find out have to code - sux, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns both private and public members. However only ones that are declared at that level, any inherited members etc. will not be returned.

Comment: How can we get private fields if they are inherited?

Comment: @ChrisKooken You might want to do a recursive search on each of the base types of the object (using TypeInfo.BaseType)

Answer (score 4):

If it is a `Property` and not a `Field` it will show private members in `DeclaredProperties`

```
public class Test
{
    private string test; // will not be in DeclaredProperties
    private string test2 { get; set; } // will be in DeclaredProperties
    public int test3{ get; set; }  // will be in DeclaredProperties
}

var result = typeof(Test).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties;
```